# Can the JVM be instructed to log full GC events only?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-arguments

The flag `-verbose:gc` causes the JVM to log all garbage collection events to stdout. This contains useful information, but lives up to its name; a minor GC tends to occur every few seconds, so other information tends to get drowned in the flood.

Is there a way to tell it to log full garbage collection events only?

Comment: No, but you may choose to 1) output all GC logs to a separate file and then grep the necessary information; 2) subscribe to [GC notifications](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.management/com/sun/management/GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo.html) through JMX and handle them right in your Java code the way you want.

Comment: @apangin imho, this should be an answer.